# Update record if exists with roo gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roo, roo-gem

I have an import working correctly from a Spreadsheet using `Roo` gem.

The problem is every time I call the rake task, new records are created.

I want to `update_attributes` of the records in case the record exists.

**Is there any way to approach this? I've tried this with no luck:**

```
namespace :import do
  desc "Import data from spreadsheet" # update this line
  task data: :environment do
  data = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('lib/t3.xlsx') # open spreadsheet
   headers = data.row(1) # get header row
   data.each_with_index do |row, idx|
     next if idx == 0 # skip header
     # create hash from headers and cells
     product_data = Hash[[headers, row].transpose]

     product = Product.new(product_data)
     puts "Guardando Producto #{product.name}"
     if product?
       product.update_attributes
     else
       product.save!
     end
     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
     puts invalid.record.errors
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if product?` will never return false. You're testing whether the variable contains a falsy value (`nil`/`false`) or *any other value*. After calling `product = Product.new`, the value stored in `product` can *never* be `nil` or `false`.

What you want is to first `find`, and if not found, `new`, and then `update_attributes` on the resulting object:

```
product = Product.find_by(product_data.name) || Product.new
product.update_attributes(product_data)
```